# PSPACE completeness, with different kinds of reductions

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, reductions, space-complexity

*PSPACE-complete$_{FP}$* problems are the *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a polynomial time reduction, i.e. the reduction is an algorithm $\in$ [*FP*](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp). This class is known as *PSPACE-complete*.

Similarly, we can define :

*PSPACE-complete$_{FPSPACE}$* problems, the  *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a polynomial space reduction. This class is still *PSPACE*, minus trivial problems $\Sigma^*$ and $\emptyset$.

*PSPACE-complete$_{FNP}$* problems, the  *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a [*FNP*](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fnp) reduction (the function problem extension of the decision problem class *NP*).

*PSPACE-complete$_{FPH}$* problems, the  *PSPACE* problems such that every other *PSPACE* problem can be transformed to it with a *FPH* reduction (the function problem extension of the decision problem class *PH*).

It seems to me that all these classes are well defined and that we have :

*PSPACE-complete* $\subset$ *PSPACE-complete$_{FNP}$* $\subset$ *PSPACE-complete$_{FPH}$* $\subset$ *PSPACE*

Additionally, if *PSPACE-complete$_{FPH}$* $\neq$ *PSPACE-complete* then *P* $\neq$ *NP*.

Naturally, *PSPACE-complete$_{FNP}$* $\neq$ *PSPACE-complete* works also but it's more difficult to prove.

What more can be found about the two last defined classes ?

(Initially asked on [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/pspace-completeness-with-different-kinds-of-reductions))

Comment: [Crosspost on cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40946/pspace-completeness-with-different-kinds-of-reductions).

Comment: Previous outdated comments deleted. A quite similar question : http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25316/nexptime-completeness-with-more-time-for-reductions

Comment: I think this is a good question.  :)